# On chastity of gods

Tags: shiva, gods, dharma, apsaras

[Tilottama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilottama) was born to kill the twin brothers Sunda-Upasunda and when Shiva first sees her, he's captivated by her beauty and [develops many heads on each side](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01214.htm) so he can keep looking at her.

Why do gods do things which are not right according to dharma?

Comment: to clarify definition - chastity is quality of woman, celibacy is quality of man.

Comment: @ram in my dialect, those words are not gendered - either may apply to any person, but chastity is more of a personal quality, while celibacy is more of a practice

Comment: @Zanna, what dialect do you use ?

Comment: @ram `celibacy` indicates abstention from all sexual matters while `chastity` means refraining one to have only marital sex or one partner. I also have seen male members being referred to as `chaste` in proper english (i.e., not translations of Indian scriptures).

Comment: @user1952500, the technical term for males with only one partner is eka-patni-vrata, while that for females is pati-vratya. celibacy or brahmacharya can be observed even during married life while having sex, as long as prohibited days are avoided, and chastity can be observed even when having multiple wives, as long as other women are avoided. a better meaning of chaste is devotion/obedience to partner. i have never heard of chaste husband in our itihasa/puranas, only chaste wife.

Comment: @ram that is the sanskrit version and celibacy is an incorrect english translation. I was talking _only_ about the english translation. Now you may say `chastity` => `brahmacharya-vrata` => `celibacy` but that does not translate correctly into english. It's like saying `arrow` => `shara` => `rain` so `arrow` and `rain` are the same. They may share the same word in sanskrit but not in other languages.

Comment: this question on this site refers to incidents mentioned in puranas which are in sanskrit. so other languages are not as relevant in meaning/translations.

Comment: @ram agreed in general, it's just very confusing to many including me. Celibacy and chastity are generally not related to any religion and a celibate person can be an atheist as well (uncommon but very common for chaste people). We have been trying to correct mistranslations of the west in many other cases, this is yet another case. We should correct this mistranslation as well.

Comment: @PravinRGMishra, Do you have valid sources from the Hindu scriptures regarding the stories made in Wiki. Wikipedia is open to anybody and if you see the paragraph you are referring, you will yourself see the many contradicting stories of the same incident. Somewhere it tells about Shiva attracted to her, and somewhere Brahma or Indra, but for each of the incidents of multiple eyes or multiple heads we have separate stories in main scriptures and not this one. So, please verify the sources first.

Comment: @Aby yes wait updating

Answer (score 2):

Accrording to saints like Sri Ramakrishna and Sri Sitaramdas Omkarnath, the exact meanings of scriptures has to be known by spiritual practice.The truth can not be known without sadhana.

Sri Ramakrishna used to say:

> One has to do sadhana to understand the real meanings of the scriptures.Sugar is mixed with sand. Sugar has to be taken discarding the sand.

Sri Sitaramas Omkarnath says:

> In purana, three types of language has been used. Laukiki (language of the masses),kavyiki(language of the poets) and of samadhi(to be understood by spiritual practice).

Let us take some ines from your source:

> A tale in the Mahabharata (Book 13) narrates that Tilottama comes to tempt Shiva. Eager to see her as she circumambulated him, Shiva developed four visible faces.
>
> Another interpretation states that Shiva revealed himself to Tilottama as the five Brahmans, with his five faces (4 visible, 1 invisible). The east face signifying his sovereignty over the world, the north face to sport with Parvati, the west to ensure the happiness of creatures; the south face, to destroy the universe and the fifth face was invisible as it was beyond the comprehension of Tilottama.
>
> Another legend from the Puranas says Brahma created Tilottama and was aroused by her. Brahma lusts for his own daughter Tilottama and makes five heads in order to see her. Then Brahma sends Tilottama to Mount Kailash, the abode of Shiva, to pay her obeisance to him. Shiva glances at her, but avoids to carefully look at her as his consort Parvati was seated beside him. As Tilottama circumambulated Shiva, he develops a head in each direction to see her. The divine sage Narada taunts Parvati, "You can imagine what Shiva is thinking about this prostitute who is reviled by wise men". Agitated, Parvati covers Shiva's eyes with her hands submerging the universe in darkness. Shiva then develops a third eye to bring light to the universe.

So first we see there are various 'legends' and 'interpretations' indicating there must be some deep inherent meaning as opposed to directly narrating some incident.

We should also remember that creating faces or eyes tell of Their Divine Powers.So We must not use yardsticks of the mortal world to judge the activities of gods.

All what we know to be right are very much present in these scriptures.The lives of our great saints are shining proof of that.

Just  to tell the real meaning in a roundabout way, such stories are created. **In our culture, Vidya is Gurumukhi and so the right meaning of these can be learned only from Guru through sadhana.**

Comment: "Sugar is mixed with sand" - why do they mix sugar & sand? These are not Vedas or Upanishads, these are Itihasas and Puranas. Also, "the right meaning of these can be learned only from Guru through sadhana" is not an answer to the question "Why do gods do things which are not right according to dharma?"